# How would I disconnect the GPU LED light?

Tags: ubuntu, gpu, nvidia-graphics-card, led

I have tried

`nvidia-settings --assign GPULogoBrightness=0`

but the LED doesn't change. It's a Zotac Nvidia GeForce RTX 3060Ti. I have seen Zotac software for Windows only. I run Ubuntu 22.04. But I was told this is a hardware issue anyways. How could I disconnect the LED logo light?

Comment: [GeForce Experience](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/geforce-experience/)
is said to allow control of the LED light. See [this article](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/geforce/news/geforce-experience-nvidia-geforce-gtx-led-visualizer-user-guide/#1). You should check if this feature exists in the RTX software.

Comment: That is a windows app.

Comment: Zotac has software also, but only for windows.

Comment: There is no equivalent Linux version?

Comment: I haven't found one

Comment: If you installed the [latest software](https://www.nvidia.com/en-us/drivers/unix/) and haven't found it, then it doesn't exist. You could perhaps use low-tech and stick a black tape over it.

Comment: Yes that's why I'm asking about a hardware option of physically removing the connection.

Comment: The connection is most likely located somewhere only accessible by removing the entire cooler assembly.

Comment: Don't traffic with your hardware, it's too costly to take chances. Black tape will be safer.

Comment: I have driver 535, looks like the latest.

Comment: Yeah I don't want to risk taking apart and damaging too much. Just wondering if people are aware of a possible simple disconnect. I may just use tape. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: Very likely it won't the GeForce Experience equivalent setting but just in case check Nvidia X Server Settings, installed alongside the Linux driver.

Comment: I looked in that, but don't see an LED logo brightness or on/off setting.

Comment: Seems like low-tech is the way to go.

Comment: It may not make much difference for over heating, but maybe using a type of thermally conductive tape may be preferable. If there is electrical type

Comment: Though electrically insulating and thermally insulating are often hand in hand lol

Comment: Tech support wrote me back and told me there is no way to turn it off. Nice feature /s